# Connecting to a subprocess stdin to pipe

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdin

I have a method that creates a subprocess and connects it STDIN to an anonymous pipe; which is not working.  Its not raising any exceptions, the subprocess just never seems to never read the data.  (the subprocess is the 'zenity' executable for displaying a progress bar in the GUI)

```
class Screen(object):
    def __init__(self, display = ":0", bin = '/usr/bin/zenity'):
        self.bin = bin
        os.environ['DISPLAY'] = display
        self.dis = display

    def displayProgress(self, text, pulse = True, title = 'Progess'):
    '''Method to represent the 'zenity --progress' command
    '''
        readp, writep = os.pipe()
        reade, writee = os.pipe()

        rfd = os.fdopen(readp, 'r')
        wfd = os.fdopen(writep, 'w')


        if pulse:
            zenhandle = Popen([self.bin, '--progress',
                                         '--title=%s' % title,
                                         '--auto-close',
                                         '--pulsate'],
                              stdin = rfd)
        else:
            zenhandle = Popen([self.bin, '--progress',
                                         '--title=%s' % title,
                                         '--auto-close'],
                              stdin = rfd)

        self.progress = wfd
```

The idea is calling the method will be non-blocking and I can `write()` to `Screen.progress` and have to written to the STDIN of the child (zenity) process. (zenity draws a completion bar graph, reading values from STDIN)

The box gets drawn on the screen, but `Screen.progress.write('50')` never updates the bar.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

If run interactively, as soon as I exit the python shell, the bar starts moving. (pulsing) Which means it read -something- only after the python process exited.

Comment: do you really need to manually make your own pipe? Why not get subprocess to handle that for you. eg `handle = subprocess.Popen('cat', stdin=subprocess.PIPE); handle.stdin.write('hello')`

Comment: That will work, from the code examples i looked at for subprocess, I thought stdin was read from args to the communicate() method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.fdopen()` should have a buffer size of 0. Use `rfd = os.fdopen(readp, 'r', 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to flush the file buffers. Try doing `self.progress.flush()` after each write.

Comment: That was it! so simple.  I changed `fdopen()` to use a bufsize of 0, and it works without flushing.  Thanks!