# Avoid time lapse between 2 processes (2 instances of OMXPlayer)

Tags: python, bash, video, raspberry-pi

OMXPlayer is currently the only player for the Raspberry Pi that supports GPU acceleration. Unfortunately, it does not support playlists and takes roughly about 2 seconds to start and I need to be able to play two or more videos without any noticeable gap between them.

I wrote a simple python wrapper around it in order to launch a new instance of OMXPlayer everytime the current video ends. This works well with large videos, but when you've got videos with a duration of approximately 10 seconds it becomes really annoying.

I've been fiddling with named pipes and had some results: the gap went down to 1.4 seconds, but that's still waaaay more than what I wanted.

Here's my current code:

```
(...)

video1 = "/home/user/video1.mp4"
video2 = "/home/user/video2.mp4"
pipe1 = "/tmp/fifo1"
pipe2 = "/tmp/fifo2"


payload = 'exec omxplayer --vol %s -o "%s" "%s" < %s' % (0, "hdmi", video1, pipe1)
start = time.time()
p1 = subprocess.Popen(payload, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), shell=True)

payload = 'exec omxplayer --vol %s -o "%s" "%s" < %s &' % (0, "hdmi", video2, pipe2)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(payload, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), shell=True)

# Let the games begin
os.system("echo -n . > %s" % pipe1)

p1.wait()

os.system("echo -n . > %s" % pipe2)

p2.wait()

end = time.time

print("ELAPSED: %g" % (end-start))
```

I also tried opening the second pipe immediately after opening the first one and then I'd pause it (by sending "p" through the pipe), only to resume playback immediately after p1.wait() but the second video wouldn't pause at all.

Any suggestions on how to minimize this? 
If anyone can pull this off using Bash scripts I'm all for it as well.

Comment: Opening two processes at startup and keeping them open sounds good. What is the problem with that?

Comment: The second video wouldn't pause; both would start playing simultaneously. If I had epilepsy i'd be dead by now.

Comment: Would really like to test that, but unfortunately I'm at work and my raspberry is at home. Can have a look in the evening, if there are no answers before...

Comment: @hek2mgl There was something wrong with the pipes! I tried the pausing technique again after recreating them and it worked. The only issues are that a) it seems to take longer for the first video to load (makes sense) and b) OMXPlayer gives a visual feedback that the second video has been paused. Thanks! If you answer the question I'll accept it :)

Comment: hehe :) Ok, I've answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening two processes at startup and keeping them open sounds good. What is the problem with that? Maybe the pipes contain some trash from previous tests? You should regerate (or flush) them.

Also you may have a look at anonymous pipes. For me it looks like they would fit better here.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269886/connecting-to-a-subprocess-stdin-to-pipe) for example to see how anonymous pipes can be used here